# How do I add all Wednesdays and Sundays?

Tags: google-sheets

I am new to Google Sheets and I am making a chart. I need all the Wednesdays and Sundays in date format in a column, but I cannot find any online tutorials. Can I please have some help?

Comment: [Welcome to Web Apps StackExchange!](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour) Could you provide an example of what this would look like? But from what I understand, you'll want to use `WORKDAY.INTL`. [Check this link for more info.](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3294972)

Answer (score 1):

If in A2 we insert the number of weeks to be taken into consideration and in B2 we insert the Wednesday of the beginning of the sequence, we could solve with this formula

```
=flatten({sequence(A2,1,B2,7),sequence(A2,1,B2+4,7)})
```

[image: sequence]

[Link to the test file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ySclMBd_vatjrwcRGW_7nZdZmqS89IHmdjrRurDzTq0/edit?usp=sharing)

**Explanation**

1. the first `sequence` creates a column of Wednesdays
2. the second `sequence` creates a Sundays column
3. the `curly brackets` that enclose the 2 sequences are used to create the range that the `Flatten` function will then unify in a single column